# What to do with concrete/cement runoff from cleaning tools?

Tags: concrete, cement

I'm completely new to working with cement/concrete. I can follow various guides online (I'm only looking at really simple loose-brick fixing for now).

However, no guide makes clear **how I should safely dispose of the runoff water from cleaning my tools and mixing tub**.

Can I just chuck this into the lawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not on the lawn! The water is caustic and can have a high pH value 10+ etc.

What I do is let the water settle. My process is as follows. I wash my mixer and tip the water into the wheelbarrow. Then I scrub the wheelbarrow and then tip the water into a rubber bucket. Then I wash the hand tools in this bucket, rinsing with a little extra fresh water into the same bucket.

So, now you have a pretty full bucket of dirty water. Leave it overnight (or longer). The solids will settle to the bottom and leave pretty clean water on the top. I usually tip this onto a gravel area if there is one (scrape back the top layer with your boot, pour and once it soaks in, push the clean gravel back over).

Then you're left with a third of a bucket of dry/set sand/cement mixture which you can scrape or knock out of the bucket and dispose of with your other 'hard' waste, brick off cuts etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Like I say I'm totally new to this. I wouldn't know where to dispose of my "other hard waste" either!

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: Clarify what to do with the 'hard waste'? That will depend on your local authorities facilities for waste management. Many places have a depot where you can take hard waste for recycling. Or you can give it away (folks use it under new driveways/paths/drainage soakaways etc.).